# Gac installation issue

Tags: c#, iis-7, .net-4.0, url-rewriting, gac

I'm following [this example on creating a custom url rewrite provider](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/804/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module/). Everything is building fine, but for some reason nothing is getting installed in the gac. Here's what I've tried in the "Post Build" command:

```
CALL "%VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat" > NULL gacutil.exe /if $(TargetPath)

CALL "%VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat" > NULL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /if $(TargetPath)

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /if $(TargetPath)

gacutil.exe" /if $(TargetPath)
```

The last one actually fails with code 9009 so the third one was used to fix it. The first two I'm totally clueless about. They don't fail, but don't seem to do anything either. The 3rd actually seems to work but navigating to c:\windows\assembly doesn't list my dll in there and when I try to add the provider in IIS it says it can't find it in the gac. My assembly is strongly signed. Any idea of whats going on?

Comment: If this is for .net 4.0 look into the new GAC location %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\

Comment: Yeah, I just found it there under the gac_32 directory. Any idea why IIS is not picking it up as an available provider?

Comment: @Sergei - Thanks for the clue. That helped me fix. My project was .net 4 but my website it running .net 3.5. If you write it up as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was having was not that I was looking in the wrong place as @Sergei suggested. I was installing it as a .NET 4.0 assembly and therefore was located elsewhere. The issue with IIS was that my website was running in .NET 3.5 and therefore could not find the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Microsoft Web Deploy Tool](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy) (v2 anyway) to install to the gac. Use the "sync" option:

```
cd "\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2"
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:gac Install="c:\path\to\file\ReplaceProvider.dll" -dest:auto
```